# Setting statement_timeout in session when is off in server

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgresql database where statement_timeout setting is set to 0. If in a session I set statement_timeout='2s' what will happen?

I think that because this setting is off in the server, a query lasting more than 2 seconds won't stop.

I tried this in a test database.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @jjanes sorry I was wrong. Session setting overrides global setting. Am I correct?